# coc.nvim leave insert compl mode with 1 esc press?

Tags: vim, neovim

When coc autocomplete is suggesting a completion nvim changes to "insert compl" mode and I have to press escape to switch to insert mode and then press escape again to go to normal mode. The only solution I found to this is to always accept a suggestion even if I typed everything out already, this is really annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turned out a plugin was causing this issue. After uninstalling "townk/vim-autoclose" i can now leave insert completion mode with 1 esc press.